# How to use the FacebookSDK workaround?

Tags: ios, facebook, json, jsonkit

After some duplicate JSON errors I've found the following Facebook SDK workaround. The owner deleted SBJSON and used JSKit instead.

Does anybody know how to use this workaround? It is not the regular FacebookSDK framework, so I am not able to implement the workaround as a framework.

Check out the workaround at: https://github.com/acani/facebook-ios-sdk

Can I just drag the src folder into Xcode and then import the "facebook.h" file? Or should I somehow build a .framework file?

Comment: What happened when you tried your suggestion?

Comment: It doesnt work. No clear error message only a warning

Comment: warning is: 

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/BLA/Desktop/.../../../../Documents/FacebookSDK'

(This directory does exist..)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? You said you were getting errors before and now you're not.

Comment: Xcode only shows the above warning, but when I hit build and run (iOS 5.0){ the simulator starts, but the screen tays black. So it doesnt load. If I change to "iOS 4.3" it does load.